# Decimal Integer literals with a leading zero are forbidden in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-debugger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSYGy.png)

```
16 17

const App()-1

10 retum [..

19 20

NavigationContainer

Stack.Navigator

21

Stack Stronn nane="Hune" carponent={Hote) /

22

Stack Screen hane-"List" component-List>

Stack.Scrom name="Login" component(Login)

24

Stack, Scronn naneap component-(Map) />

Stack Sernun, nane-batch componente Entch) A

// Stack Screen nam Tatitur cutuulient-(Tammar) />()

27

/Stack Bavigators

S

Decimal integer literals with a leading zero are forbidden in strict mode

Login a

Decimal integer literals with a leading zero are forbidden in strict mode

OAP

D

+

G

node modules

no stack

no stack

App is

flowconfic

29

31 .) }}

32 3

33

35 1/27 Tah Navigation

Tub Screen rate Tabbiar component-(Tabbar/

37

//// </Tankarigatar>

38

42

expert default App;
```

Comment: Leading zero on decimal numbers mean octal notation

Comment: and using a leading zero for an octal literal [throws an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal) in strict mode

Comment: Presumably the debugger translates the error from being about octal numbers into the  use case of putting a leading zero on what was meant to be a decimal number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean your gradle of android  using :-

```
cd android


./gradlew clean
```

And restart the metro by clearing the cache

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).